# Getting a random value from a column in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing War the Card Game in VBA Excel. I would like to get a random value from column A and column B. I researched it and it seems that this is able to generate a random number.

```
Dim ws As Sheet1

P1LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
P2LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

P1Cards = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(A1, P1LR)
P2Cards = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(A1, P2LR)
```

However it is giving me the value of the row and not the value that's actually in the cell. How would I get that value using this function?

Comment: `P1Cards = ws.Range("A1:A" & P1LR).offset(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, P1LR-1)).value`

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm getting Error 91 on this. Apparently I'm not specifying a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can address the cell by the variable, try like this:

```
Dim ws As Sheet1

P1LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
P2LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

P1Cards = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(A1, P1LR),
P2Cards = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(A1, P2LR)

Cells(P1Cards, 1).Select    
Cells(P2Cards, 2).Select
```

Or

```
Cells(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(A1, P1LR), 1).Select    
Cells(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(A1, P2LR), 2).Select
```

Comment: `A1` and `B1` are undeclared variables,  equivalent to `0`

Comment: I would also use the parent sheet since it is assigned: `P1LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` etc.

Comment: Thank you. This worked.

Comment: This is going to blow up when `RandBetween` returns `0`. The `A1` should just be `1`.